# Determine if two methods have the same base definition

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I've just made the unfortunate (for my app at least) discovery that two methods declared inside a generic class do not have the same base definition, demonstrated best in code:

```
    public static class Test
    {
        private class Generic<T> { public void Method() { } }
        public static void TestBase()
        {
            var x = typeof(Generic<int>).GetMethod("Method");
            var y = typeof(Generic<double>).GetMethod("Method");
            Debug.Assert(x.GetBaseDefinition() == y.GetBaseDefinition()); // fails
        }
    }
```

Both x and y.IsGeneric is false, so GetGenericMethodDefinition cannot be used.

The only solution I've been able to think of so far is to compare their names and that their declaring types are the same generic type, but in the presence of overloads that seems very brittle..

So.. I don't suppose there's a helpful method I've missed in the reflection library that can tell me if these two methods have been first declared in the same class? Or a workaround?

EDIT:

To clarify, I want to make a method:

```
    public bool DeclaredInSameClass(MethodInfo a, MethodInfo b);
```

which returns true if both a and b are both first declared in the same class.

Ignoring generics, this is simple: `a.GetBaseDefinition() == y.GetBaseDefinition()`, but how to handle methods declared within generic classes?

Comment: Wouldn't you simply request to see if the MethodsCollection contained a reference to the selected MethodInfo? Perhaps a use case to illustrate when this would be useful?

Comment: The fact that the type is different between the two realizations of the templates means they are different by definition.  You say you want to see if they are defined in the same class, but Generic<int> is not quite the same class as Generic<double>.

Comment: @ James (/Tejs), unfortunately that they're declared in the same class means a great deal to me. Basically I want to be able to know if two classes, each sharing a heap of properties, have any parts in common - to allow copying of settings from one class to another. This isn't for just any class - I do have control over the classes and it's for internal use only, but it would be -very- useful to know. Properties complicates things further though, so I'm happy to leave the question at methods ;). It all currently works very well until generics get involved I might add..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT... one last try:

```
    private class Generic<T> { 
        public void Method() { }
        public void Method(string param) { }
        public void OtherMethod() { }  
    }
    private class NonGeneric { public void Method() { } }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = typeof(Generic<int>).GetMethod("Method", new Type[]{});
        var y = typeof(Generic<double>).GetMethod("Method", new Type[]{});
        var a = typeof(Generic<double>).GetMethod("OtherMethod");
        var b = typeof(NonGeneric).GetMethod("Method");
        var c = typeof(Generic<int>).GetMethod("Method", new Type[] { typeof(string) });

        Debug.Assert(DeclaredInSameClass(x, y));
        Debug.Assert(!DeclaredInSameClass(x, a));
        Debug.Assert(!DeclaredInSameClass(x, b));
        Debug.Assert(!DeclaredInSameClass(x, c));
        Debug.Assert(!DeclaredInSameClass(a, b));

    }

    public static bool DeclaredInSameClass(MethodInfo a, MethodInfo b)
    {
        if (a.DeclaringType.IsGenericType != b.DeclaringType.IsGenericType)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (a.DeclaringType.IsGenericType)
        {

            var x = a.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetMethod(a.Name, a.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
            var y = b.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetMethod(b.Name, b.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
            return x.Equals(y);
        }
        return a.GetBaseDefinition().Equals(b.GetBaseDefinition());
    }
```

Comment: I'm really hoping to not resort to resolving methods by name, I realise in the example I do - but in the real app I already have both MethodInfos. Grabbing their names and searching for them in the presence of both overloads and property hiding (with new operator) etc will break for me. Am all too familiar with AmbiguousMatchException..

Comment: you should clarify the question... i was just making your failing test pass

Comment: @robert - updated. Your updated solution returns true for any two methods declared in the same generic class, unfortunately no good. In the original post I proposed just that + a name check, but that fails with overloads :(.

Comment: @mania - one more update for you to handle checking for specific overloads

Comment: @Robert Regards. Name, type and parameters.. for good measure I'll probably check returns too, in case I'm ever using a class from some curveball language or an obfuscater, but this does all I'll realistically ever need :). Thanks.